# How do I handle message passing from one object to another that has a common abstract class in C++

Tags: c++

I have a base class INotify which has a virtual function notify. This method is inherited by two classes Event and Receiver. I want a method add() in Event that adds reference of objects of class Receiver in container so that I can use it to pass message to Receiver class through the method notify as both inherits the common property notify from parent INotify. I do not know much about C++ so please give explanation. I have enclosed the basic skeleton of my program.

```
using namespace std;
//Base Abstract class
class INotify
{
    public:
    virtual void notify(string msg)=0;
};

//Receiver class receives message from Event
class Receiver:public INotify
{
    string message;
    public:
    void notify(string msg)
    {
        message=msg;
    }
    void display()
    {
        cout<<message;
    }
};

//Event class that sends message to Receiver
class Event:public INotify
{
    public:
    Event()
    {
    }
    void notify(string msg)
    {
        container[0].notify(msg);
    }
    INotify *container=new Event[1];

    void add(Receiver &obj)
    {
        container[0]=obj;
    }
};



int main()
{
    Receiver recObj;//Create receiver object
    Event eventObj;//create event object
    eventObj.add(recObj);//adds reference of receiver object in container
    eventObj.notify("Test Test"); //sends message to receiver object's notify method
    recObj.display();//displays the message from receiver
}
```

Comment: Sounds for me as bad design. Deriving from INotify for Receiver and for Event looks absolutely strange! Even it could be implemented, I can understand that a Receiver can be notified, but an event will not itself be notified. The receiver will be notified with an event. But this not what your code looks like!

Comment: I want to pass a message in object of Event and it should also be received in the Receiver class. Don't look at the code design. You can suggest any design.

Comment: Very bad design. `container[0]=obj` Here you're casting obj from Receiver to Event, a sister class!

Comment: It looks like you're (ab)using the verb "notify" to mean both "notify someone else about something" and "receive notification about something". This dual meaning will not do much good to your program's structure.

Comment: You start with a code example and now your question is about designing a message infrastructure. That is not longer related to C++ and is a bit broad to answer with a simple example and there are a lot of models already available. Starting by single/slot libraries from different vendors, or having GoF pattern "observer" which uses registering observers to some entities which will notify them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change your Event class

```
//Event class that sends message to Receiver
class Event:public INotify
{
public:
Event()
{
}
void notify(string msg)
{
    container[0]->notify(msg);
}
vector<INotify *>container;

void add(INotify &obj)
{
    container.push_back(&obj);
}
};
```